# How to close a specific Tab in Browser using UI Automation.?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.5, ui-automation

I want to close a specific Tab in Browser.let's take an example such as if he try to open facebook then that tab has to closed, presently the whole process is getting killed.

```
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
if (element != null)
 {
   ((WindowPattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern)).Close();
 }
```

How can i close Specific Tab.

Comment: Which browser? IE?

Comment: Not specific to IE, any browser.?

Comment: Not all browser work the same, they don't present the same UI tree to UI automation tools/API.

Comment: presently i am able to know the process Name and the window Title irrespective of browser by using window title can i close the browser Tab.? presently the above code is killing whole process.:(